# signing transactions with web3.js

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, web3-providers

Im trying to create a node.js based dapp that interacts with ropsten ethereum network via infura node.here we need sign transaction with web3.js. but the code showing error from the contract side. please let me know what seems to be the problem

```
let myData=contract.methods.greet("hello blockchain devs").encodeABI()
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'greet' of undefined
```

here is my code:

```
var Tx     = require('ethereumjs-tx')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/<API KEY>')

const account1 = '<account address>' // Your account address 1

const privateKey1 = Buffer.from('<Private Key>', 'hex')
const abi=[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_greeting","type":"string"}],"name":"greet","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getGreeting","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];
const contract_Address="0xcbe74e21b070a979b9d6426b11e876d4cb618daf";
const contract =web3.eth.contract(abi, contract_Address)
let myData=contract.methods.greet("hello blockchain devs").encodeABI()
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {
  // Build the transaction
  const txObject = {
    nonce:    web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    to:       contract_Address,
    value:    web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether')),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
    data: myData
  }

  // Sign the transaction
  const tx = new Tx(txObject)
  tx.sign(privateKey1)

  const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
  const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

  // Broadcast the transaction
  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
    console.log('txHash:', txHash)
    // Now go check etherscan to see the transaction!
  })
})
```

Comment: Dude why are you sending ether with your transaction, i thought your greet(--=) method only change the String?!?!

Comment: I think you also need "new" before "web3.eth.contract(abi, contract_Address)"

Answer (score 1):

Fix:

const contract = **new** web3.eth.**Contract**(abi, contract_Address);

gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(**2100000**)

**value:    web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')),**

Answer (score 0):

try using
`let myData=contract.methods.greet("hello blockchain devs").call()` if it is view or pure type function.
else use
`res = contract.methods.greet('your msg').send({from : <caller address>})`

**Note**

1. make sure your contract abi and address is correct
2. try check the contract instance that is correctly instantiated by using
   `console.log(contract)` so that you can check that its not undifined
3. make sure the greet function available in your contract.

Comment: This is a 4 year old question, that a previous response appears to answer fully.